# How to fix falling out electric socket?

Tags: repair, socket

I've a Type C electric socket that not holds solidly in a wall slot.

It uses metallic lateral ears and a pair of screws which controls their angle to hold itself into a wall socket.

Wall socket is concrete.

Is there any way to fix it solidly into this wall socket?

Comment: A photo or two would be a tremendous help toward getting folks up to speed on your problem.

Comment: Use [spacers](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/28290/how-do-i-extend-outlets-after-installing-a-backsplash/28317#28317).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a 90 degree, type C plug

[image]

And then fasten to the wall, with a couple of cable clamps

[image]

A clamp close to the outlet and it will be difficult to remove, and clamps down or along the wall will keep it safe.

Hope this helps